# How to let component know which context calls the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Suppose I have a component and two contexts. The both contexts can use this component. When context1 uses it, the component should do `const context=useContext(Context1)` in itself. When context2 uses it, the component should do `const context=useContext(Context2)` in itself. But how can this component know which context is using it now and do the instuction?

OK, I will give an easy example of it but the real situation is more complex than it, for example, Common is wrapped many times and the two components look different.

The common component

```js
export default function Common(){
  const context=useContext(/*one of the context*/);
  context.setData(newData);
  return (
     <div>{context.data}</div>
  )
}
```

Component1

```js
export const Context1 = createContext({ data, setData });

export default function Component1() {
  <Context1.Provider value={{data, setData }}>
     <Common />
  </Context1.Provider>
}
```

Component2

```js
export const Context2 = createContext({ data, setData  });

export default function Component2() {
  <Context2.Provider value={{data, setData }}>
     <Common />
  </Context2.Provider>
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question...

Comment: @Yameen I have refined the question, could you please tell me whether it is clear enough?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Contexts don't use components. Components use contexts.

Comment: I wonder how to know  which context is using the component, or the component cannot know which context should be used.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to choose a context?

Comment: Because two contexts will use this component.

Comment: Last time: what are you trying to do? What are the contexts? Why do you need to choose a context?

Comment: I'm sorry for not able to make you understand but I have tried my best to explain my question. I want to make the component know which context it will use.

Comment: The wording of the question is seriously confusing. Can you provide a minimal code example?

Comment: @Martin I have tried giving a mini example.

Comment: @SNORLAX in your example, you don't need to have two different createContext(). You only need one and set a different `setData` for each Provider.

Answer (score 2):

If you've got a component that has to choose which context to use I think you should rethink your design. It would be much easier to help if you would explain what the two contexts are and what the component is doing with them, but you don't seem willing to elaborate.

Is there a reason you can't have a single context whose *value* changes, instead of entirely separate contexts? I guess I'll never know.

If you insist on having two contexts and making your component choose between them you could have a context that specifies which context to use.

```js
const Context1 = React.createContext("I'm context one!");
const Context2 = React.createContext("I'm context two!");

const WhichContext = React.createContext(Context1);

function MyComponent() {
  const which = React.useContext(WhichContext);
  const context = React.useContext(which);
  
  return (
    <div>{context}</div>
  );
}

function App () {
  return (
    <WhichContext.Provider value={Context2}>
      <MyComponent />
    </WhichContext.Provider>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

You could also just pass it in as a prop:

```js
const Context1 = React.createContext("I'm context one!");
const Context2 = React.createContext("I'm context two!");

const WhichContext = React.createContext(Context1);

function MyComponent(props) {
  const context = React.useContext(props.context);
  
  return (
    <div>{context}</div>
  );
}

function App () {
  return (
      <MyComponent context={Context2} />
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I have given a mini example and that may make the question more clear.

Comment: Your updated example doesn't really add any new information. I understand that you've got more than one context and you're using a common component, but I still don't know why or what the difference is between the contexts. I'm still convinced there's a better way, but without some specifics it's impossible to say.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Now I understand that I can only use one context to do this. Sincere thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

You can try making storing some key value in the local storage and get the value in the component from there .

like in context1 just add one line

```
localStorage.setItem('currentcontext', 'context1');
```

and in context2 be

```
localStorage.setItem('currentcontext', 'context2');
```

now then your component loads just retrive the value from the clocalstorage by

```
var current = localStorage.getItem('currentcontext');
```

then you will have the currently used context name stored in current named variable..

i tried to answer based on how much i came to get your problem if you face any other issue do comment...

Comment: Or just have a third context that specifies whether to use context one or two. 

Comment: @ray  you'r right but what you thing my approach was good enough or not?

Comment: No. There's no reason to shove something into storage and pull it back out again when making information available deep in the component hierarchy is exactly what context does in the first place. OP could put which context to use in the context itself, but it's not at all clear what OP is even trying to do. This is idiotic but it would work: `const which = useContext(WhichContext); const context = useContext(which);` I'm pretty sure OP doesn't need 2 contexts at all. Just set the context _value_ at the provider and use that to inform component-level logic.

Comment: How does the component know whichContext it should use in this line `const which = useContext(WhichContext)` ? That's what I want to ask.

Comment: This answer can work.

Comment: @SNORLAX if does plz dont forgot to accept the answer 

Comment: This is not the way to solve this.

Comment: Maybe this is not the best way, but there is no better way now.

Comment: You might as well just have a `<WhichContext.Provider value={Context1}>` and do `useContext(useContext(WhichContext))`.

Comment: So how does WhichContext know which context is in use?

Comment: The value of WhichContext is the context to use.

Comment: As nobody is pointing it... @SNORLAX, @Geekyvinayak this solution is very problematic and unpredictable. If the app is open in two tabs, the `localStorage` is shared. Also if the two context can be used in one single page: the render cycle of React components is more complex and it could be that the last `localStorage.setItem()` call doesn't match with the Context that has our component nested. It will probably match on the first render but when state/props changes begin it is unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that the need to do this is probably a missunderstand of React design, should be not needed; and while *ray* answer seems more "React way" and elegant... I will give another option.

You could add some flag or info in the default Context values that define if the Context is actually available:

```
const Context1 = createContext({available: false})

const Component = () => {
   const context1 = useContext(Context1)
   console.log(context1.available)
   return <div />
}
```

```
<Component /> // <-- will print "false"
<Context1.Provider value={{available: true}}>
  <Component /> // <-- will print "true"
</Context1.Provider>
```

Edit, more clearly for your specific use with two contexts:

```
const Context1 = createContext({available: false, /* your other Context1 default values */})
const Context2 = createContext({available: false, /* your other Context2 default values */})

const Component = () => {
   const context1 = useContext(Context1)
   const context2 = useContext(Context2)
   if(context1.available) {
      console.log("Context1 is available, use it as needed")
   } else if(context2.available) {
      console.log("Context2 is available, use it as needed")
   } else {
      console.error("No context1 or context2 found!!")
   }
   return <div />
}
```

```
<Context1.Provider value={{available: true, /* other context1 values */}}>
  <Component />
</Context1.Provider>
<Context2.Provider value={{available: true, /* other context2 values */}}>
  <Component />
</Context2.Provider>
```

Of course, this won't help if the contexts are "nested".

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding the relationship between these code and my question.

Comment: Well this code checks if the context is available. You can use the idea to check if Context1 or Context2 like: `if(context1.available) { /* use context1 */ } else if(context2.available) { /* use context2 */} else { /* error? */ }`